# Trouble replacing non-www domains in nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration, redirect, rewrite

I'm using CentOS 7 with Nginx.  I want to convert all non-www domains to "www" domains, e.g. if someone enters "abc.example.com", I'd like them to be redirected to "www.example.com".  I tried this

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name "~^(?!www\.).*";
  return 301 $scheme://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```

in my site-specific configuration file, but instead what's happening is if someone enters "abc.example.com", they are redirected to "www.abc.example.com".  How can I correct the above to replace rather than pre-pend "www"?

Comment: How do you determine what part to keep? Is it always the last two components of the domain name? Would you redirect `amazon.co.uk` to `www.co.uk`?

Comment: In my case, I only have "example.com" as the domain.  So anything in front of the domain, e.g. "abcdef.example.com" or "abc.def.ghi.example.com" shoudl be redirected to "www.example.com".  Additionally, simply entering "example.com" should redirect to "www.example.com."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only hosting `example.com` domain and want everything to be redirected to `www.example.com`, you should use a default server rather than a regular expression server.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) for more.